# Loading certain files in list.files() and storing those in a dataframe

Tags: r, string, stringr

I would like to read all the files that start with Sample51* and store their first columns into a dataframe with their specific IDs.

```
list.files("~/Desktop/OUT/", pattern="Sample51*")
```

> ```
> [1] "Sample51-24.file.path.txt"
> [2] "Sample50-26.file.path.txt"
> [3] "Sample51-15123.file.path.txt"
> [4] "Sample49-123.file.path.txt"
> [5] "Sample51-412.file.path.txt"
> [6] "Sample51-921.file.path.txt"
> [7] "Sample49-02341.file.path.txt"
> [8] "Sample51-1324.file.path.txt"
> ```

The IDs are:

Sample51-"$ID".file.path.txt.

and it would turn into `paste0("S_51_", ID)`

```
S_51_24 <- data.frame(read.table(file="Sample51-24.file.path.txt", header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1]
S_51_15123 <- data.frame(read.table(file="Sample51-15123.file.path.txt", header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1]
S_51_412 <- data.frame(read.table(file="Sample51-412.file.path.txt", header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1]
S_51_921 <- data.frame(read.table(file="Sample51-921.file.path.txt", header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1]
S_51_1324 <- data.frame(read.table(file="Sample51-1324.file.path.txt", header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1]
```

Should I use a for loop? I am not sure how to generate the names and then store my dataframes in them.

```
for (i in list.files("~/Desktop/OUT/", pattern="Sample51*")){
   ID=???
   ID <- data.frame(read.table(file=i, header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
#List all the files with complete path which has the pattern
all_files <- list.files("~/Desktop/OUT/", pattern="^Sample51*", full.names = TRUE)
#Read the 1st column of all the files
all_data <- lapply(all_files, function(x) 
                       read.table(x, header=TRUE, row.names=1, sep="\t")[,1])
#Name the list based on their ID
names(all_data) <- sub('Sample51-(\\d+).*', "S_51_\\1", basename(all_files))
```

Comment: Does this produce a list?

Comment: @user171558 yes `all_data` is a list with one column of each dataframe.

Comment: gotcha! I turned it into a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you are asking, but I would suggest something else instead. Having variables with names that are unknown up-front makes it hard to work with them downstream. Instead, keep the identifiers in a vector for future reference and load the data like this:

```
files = list.files("~/Desktop/OUT/", pattern="Sample51*")
ids = sub("Sample(.*)\\.file\\.path\\.txt", "\\1", files)
all.data = list()
for (i in ids){
    f = paste0("~/Desktop/OUT/Sample", i, ".file.path.txt")
    all.data[[i]] <- read.table(file=f, header=T, row.names=1, sep="\t")
}
```

Now pull the data frame for a particular sample like this:

```
all.data[["51_412"]]
```

Comment: sub() works! I'll play around and edit if I was able to load these as a dataframe